# Converting system.windows.media.brush to Hex color code

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, colors, windows-phone-7.1

In my Windows phone7 application I placed a canvas and have set its background color to some hex color code.Now I am not able get the hex color code value through c# code.I used the below code but it give the color value in system.windows.media.brush.Plz help me with an answer?

```
clr = Convert.ToString(clr1.Background);
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems it returns a `Brush` and since you've set a color it should return a `SolidColorBrush`. Try this

```
var color = ((SolidColorBrush)clr1.Background).Color.ToString();
```

Example:

```
var color = new Color() {R = 0xF0, G = 0x10, B = 0x80};
var brush = new SolidColorBrush(color);
var hexcolor = brush.Color.ToString();
```

`hexcolor` equals `"#00F01080"`

Comment: hi jonas,it didnt work.it return System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush.

Comment: Yes? A SolidColorBrush should have a Color property and that was what I was trying to use.

Comment: So is it possible to convert System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush to hex color code?

Comment: Yes it is, and that is exactly what I tried to achieve above. Added another example.