# Converting RGB/Brush to Hexadecimal value

Tags: c#

So, In my program I have 3 sliders, SliderRed, SliderGreen, Slider Blue. They all have a maximum value of 255. The control called `EndColor` changes colors correctly when I move the sliders but I haven't figured out a way to get the hexcode.text (Textblock) to convert the brush or color into a hexadecimal value such as `#FF0000`.

What should I be using for this to work?

```
public void SliderChanged()
{
    byte r = byte.Parse(sliderRed.Value.ToString());
    byte g = byte.Parse(sliderGreen.Value.ToString());
    byte b = byte.Parse(sliderBlue.Value.ToString());

    EndColor.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, r, g, b));
    hexcode.Text = EndColor.Background.ToString(); //Something like this
}
```

All I need is the `hexcode.Text` to show a hexadecimal value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set System.Drawing.Color values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016456/set-system-drawing-color-values)

Comment: Eh formatting? `String.Format("{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}", EndColor.Background.Red, EndColor.Background.Green, EndColor.Background.Blue);`

Comment: @GurfX this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160141/converting-system-windows-media-brush-to-hex-color-code) might help you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firstly let me point out that, assuming that your sliders' `value` property returns an int, you're converting an `int` to a `string` and then back again. This is not necessary. Instead of

```
byte r = byte.Parse(sliderRed.Value.ToString());
```

all you need to do is

```
byte r = (byte)sliderRed.Value;
```

This bypasses the string conversion. Converting something to a string and then converting it back from a string to something else is a code smell that should make you stop and think if there isn't a better way.

To turn the colour into its hex code is easy, because you already have the R, G and B values. All you need is:

```
hexCode.Text = string.Format("#{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}", r, g, b);
```

Formatting a number with the format string `"X2"` forces it to render in hexadecimal, with 2 digits. So you just do that for all three next to each other, and stick the hash symbol at the front.

**edit**

If you're passing colour data around between parts of your code, you should always do that with a `System.Drawing.Color` object, and then whenever you need to display a hex string, generate that at the time. Don't pass around the hex string and convert it back to a `Color` when it's needed. Remember how I said converting things to strings and back again was a code smell?

If you find you're doing it a lot then it makes sense to add an extension method to `Color` so that you can call it easily. Here's a class that implements that method:

```
static class ColorExtensions
{
    public static string ToHexString(this System.Drawing.Color color)
    {
        return string.Format("#{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}", color.R, color.G, color.B);
    }
}
```

This will give all `Color` values a `ToHexString()` method, which in your code above you could use as follows:

```
var color = Color.FromArgb(255, r, g, b);
EndColor.Background = new SolidColorBrush(color);
hexcode.Text = color.ToHexString();
```

Comment: Now for my control if I wanted to change something around, How would i make it do something like this `EndColor.Background = hex;`

Comment: You mean you want to use the hex string to set the colour of the visual component? If you really must, then you can write a small parser that throws away the hash symbol and then reads two characters for each of red, green and blue, and then constructs a colour for that. Don't do that though. `System.Drawing.Color` exists and that's how you should pass around colour information between the internals of your code. Write yourself a function that converts a `System.Drawing.Color` into a hex string (you could even make it an extension method), and use that whenever you need the string.

Comment: Is it possible to do it all in one line? If so, do you mind writing it in the comments?

Answer (score 1):

`hexcode.Text = ((SolidColorBrush)(EndColor.Background)).Color.ToString();` should do it.

Note that the `Color.ToString()` used here is the `System.Windows.Media.Color.ToString()` implementation (because `SolidColorBrush` is part of the `System.Windows.Media` classes.

`System.Drawing.Color.ToString()` will give different results - see
see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/50cb8sdx(v=vs.110).aspx [Drawing] vs https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms606572(v=vs.110).aspx [Media]

Comment: Background Does not contain a definition named color

Comment: Try `(EndColor.Background as SolidColorBrush).Color.ToString()`

Comment: `Color.ToString()` does not return a string in the format '#FF0DBB'. It returns something like: `Color [A=255, R=255, G=13, B=187]`

Comment: Me too, Also with this is there a way to remove the Alpha of the hex code

because mine ends up with #FFFFFFFF if it is fully opaque and white

Comment: you can certainly do it manually - `if (hexcode.Text.Length > 7)
   hexcode.Text= hexcode.Text.Remove(1,2);`

Comment: Very strange that we're getting different results from `Color.ToString`! Perhaps a good reason not to use it.

Comment: This could explain it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/50cb8sdx(v=vs.110).aspx vs https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms606572(v=vs.110).aspx (System.Drawing vs. System.Windows.Media). As SolidColorBrush is part of the System.Windows.Media library, that one will be the .ToString() used - i.e. the hex representation.